# CMD will not find g++, regardless of it being in my Environment Path

Tags: c++, windows, mingw-w64

I am on the C++ struggle bus...

Context: Last night I had g++ working perfectly fine, I found out that the installation I had was not compatible with some of the libraries I was trying to work with. As a matter of fact, MSYS was downloading 32 bit compilers when I wanted a 64 bit.

I figured I did something wrong so I deleted the installation, by hand, and then went ahead and reran
the MSYS installer for mingw64, re setup the Environment Variable Path and now it no longer works (from the command prompt at least)

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgNWQ.png)

g++ is no longer operating from the Command Prompt.

I made sure to close and reopen CMD. Failed.  I tried running as administrator (not that it would really help) and failed. I reset the computer, failed.  I downloaded a mingw64 installation separate from MSYS and that also would not work when /bin was set as an environment variable.

Perhaps I am doing this wrong. I have looked everywhere, and can not seem to find a solution.

I do not know where the problem is coming from.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Try using `g++.exe`?

Comment: On the one hand, changes to the Windows Environment variables typically require a reboot. On the other, a proper MSYS2 installation takes care of that for you; you shouldn't have to muck around with PATH.

Comment: Show the contents of the PATH. Or just use the shell MSYS2 comes with, which has the correct PATH by default.

Comment: @sweenish Huh? Normally you just restart the application, no reboot necessary.

Comment: That has not been my experience when editing PATH in Windows. I know it can be done without a reboot, but I'm also pretty sure it's not as simple as starting cmd.exe. Linux and macOS, sure. And again, a proper MSYS2 installation of minGW means you shouldn't have to edit the PATH manually anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You must include `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` ***into*** the `Path` variable, that is:

[Environment Variables window] -> [click on *Path*] -> [Edit] -> [New] -> [Your Path]

Comment: You are an absolute winner and I wish you the best of luck in life. Thank you, it worked.

Comment: @LandonLuman When you can (you might need to wait a day or two), please accept this answer if it solved your problem.  That's the way the site works.  Thx